# How to update current url of view page so that it will filter correct result?

Tags: views, uri

I have created view to search nodes of video from content type channel. I have set the URL as channel/%/search in view. when redirected to the page the the URL will be `channel/all/channel-search?title=test`. But I want to replace 'all' with 'nid' which I have got by php code. In short I want to replace `channel/all/channel-search?title=test` with `channel/*NID*/channel-search?title=test` (nid may be anything channel/26). I have written the code in views contextual filter but it is not working.

```
$path = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$filter = preg_replace('///','',parse_url($path,PHP_URL_PATH),1);
$path = drupal_lookup_path("source", $filter);
$node = menu_get_object("node", 1, $path);
$nid=$node->nid;
return $nid;
```

Comment: Can i fetch the current url, update it and redirect user to the updated url. IS IT POSSSIBLE???

Comment: How and from where you are redirecting?

Comment: I am on sitemap/channel/natural-purity where i got nid of Natural Purity node. Now I am being redirected to the page channel/*NID*/search?title=nature. I have a block on channel/*NID*/search?title=nature which is giving me nid from previous url. How to set that nid to the current page i.e channel/*NID*/search?title=nature ( which should be channel/555/search?title=nature if nid=555).

Comment: I am asking, How you are redirecting?. Manually using drupal_goto() or any other manner.

Comment: I have used exposed form in block so itself it redirects to the view page from the page on which the exposed form (i.e filter in view) is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing your way, try out the following

Implement `hook_form_alter()` and modify the `#action` attribute of views exposed form.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
 if($form['#id']=='views-exposed-form-frontpage-page'){
  $node = menu_get_object("node", 1);
  if(!is_null($node)) {
     $form['#action']=$form['#action']."/".$node->nid;
  }
 } 
}
```

And then in your view add a contextual filter `Content:nid` and provide default value as **Content ID from URL**

Note : The code I tested with frontpage view, so replace the `form id` with your own.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new contextual filter, select 'Node: Nid', then check 'Provide default value' and in the select box choose 'Content ID from URL'

Comment: But what I want is, nid should be of previously uploaded node id. The nid from referer url to be passed as contextual filter to the view page which is being viewed.